# What are the Inbound and Outbound Rules for connecting a Lambda (inside a VPC) to SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect my Lambda function to SQS. The lambda function will send a message to SQS. **The Lambda is inside a VPC.**

Assume, all Inbound and Outbound Rules are **Denied** by Default (due to security protocols), and either Inbound or Outbound rules will be enabled based on requirement. Example - If Lambda inside VPC requires access to S3, then one needs to manually allow Outbound Rules to S3 Endpoint

Now, I tried with only

- Inbound Rule
- Outbound Rule

at a time, and the task timed out, because the VPC needs to connect to SQS HTTPS link. So, based on my understanding , we need

- an incoming rule for Lambda from the SQS - to get the message Id after successful
- an outgoing rule for Lambda - to connect to the SQS

An **Endpoint** `Interface` is to make sure that any interaction to and from the Lambda does not go out of the VPC.

My questions are :-

1. What are the CIDR values for Inbound and Outbound Rules ? I am
   allowing all IPs in HTTPS Port 443. But, I want to know, if there
   would be any exact values for the CIDRs. The Interface for SQS is
   not being shown in the CIDR option list.
2. Why is Inbound Rule not required when lambda is connected to S3
   and/or DynamoDB , rather only Outbound rule is required towards S3
   and DynamoDB Endpoints (to get the response from S3 or DynamoDB, like Data added in DynamoDB or S3 object is successfully deleted, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

There are two networking options for AWS Lambda functions:

**Option 1: Not connected to a VPC**
When a Lambda function is *not* connected to a VPC, it automatically has access to the Internet. This means it can make API calls to other AWS services that are on the Internet (eg send a message to an Amazon SQS Queue). This is the preferred way to configure a Lambda function if it does not need to communicate with resources inside a VPC.

**Option 2: Connected to a VPC**
If the Lambda function needs access to resources in a VPC (eg an Amazon RDS database), then you can connect the Lambda function to a **private subnet** in the VPC. It will be able to communicate with other resources in the VPC, but **it will not have access to the Internet** by default. To provide access to the Internet, you will need a NAT Gateway in a public subnet (charges apply).

**Security Groups for AWS Lambda functions**
Lambda functions are typically configured to **permit all outbound traffic**. This is because you can 'trust' your own code running in the Lambda function. Lambda functions **cannot accept inbound traffic** so Inbound rules are typically configured to disallow all inbound traffic. When connecting to resources inside a VPC, it is a good practice to put one Security Group on the Lambda function (with Allow All Outbound) and a different security group on the resource (eg the Amazon RDS database) that permits Inbound access from the Security Group associated with the Lambda function. Having the Database security group reference the Lambda security group allows the Lambda function to communicate with the database without having to hard-code any IP addresses.

**Triggering Lambda from an Amazon SQS queue**
If you want your AWS Lambda function to process messages from an Amazon SQS Queue, you can configure the Queue as a **trigger** on the Lambda function. This will tell the AWS Lambda service to automatically poll the queue and, if message(s) are found, it will invoke the Lambda function, with the message being passed via the `event` parameter. When the Lambda function successfully completes, the AWS Lambda service will delete the message from the queue. Thus, the Lambda function **does not actually need to call the Amazon SQS API** to receive or delete messages. Thus, it does not actually need Internet access, nor a VPC Endpoint for SQS (unless other parts of your code require such access). See: [Using Lambda with Amazon SQS - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)

To specifically answer your questions:

- **Inbound rule:** Deny all (nothing may be *sent* to a Lambda function)
- **Outbound rule:** Allow all
- No need to configure anything for SQS connectivity since it is provided by the AWS Lambda service

Comment: Lambda Function is going to need access to SQS since it needs to read the message. So, Security Group should perhaps need access to Inbound and Outbound. My question is why both Inbound and Outbound rules are required ? And why are inbound rules not required for S3 connection to Lambda (when Lambda is inside VPC ) (also, please consider that all Outbound rules are also blocked by default)

Comment: Is your intention for the Amazon SQS Queue to **trigger** the AWS Lambda function whenever a message is available? If so, it **does not** need access to SQS because the messages are passed-in with the invocation. However, if your Lambda function is separately reading the SQS queue, then the Security Group will require **outbound** access to the SQS endpoint. Security groups are _stateful_, so only Outbound access is required -- responses will be automatically permitted back to the Lambda function. Basically, Lambda functions **never** require inbound rules.

Comment: I tried to give Outbound access to all IP Addresses. Even then, the Lambda was unable to read SQS Message. When I gave Inbound access to all IP Addresses, then Lambda was able to read SQS Message. That is why I have confusion

Comment: A you referring to a Security Group on the Lambda function, or on the VPC Endpoint? Also, is there a specific reason why you have connected the Lambda function to the VPC?

Comment: I have a security group associated with Lambda function, which has Inbound and Outbound rules, not the VPC Endpoint. In our project, we need to have every possible service hosted inside a VPC